# spring thymeleaf pagnation with plain hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, pagination, thymeleaf

Hi i want to implement pagination with spring mvc app with thymeleaf.
Some how i have created the pagination, but it is only showing first 20 objects only, And no pagination after that(disabled on ui side). I'm using plain hibernate criteria with spring data Pageable object.

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/articles.html", "/" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAtricles(Model model, Pageable pageable) {
        Page<Article> articlePages = articleService.findAll(pageable);
        PageWrapper<Article> page = new PageWrapper<Article>(articlePages, "/articles.html");
        model.addAttribute("articles", page.getContent());
        model.addAttribute("page", page);
        return "index";
    }
```

Dao implemnetation

```
public Page<Article> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
    Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(Article.class);
    c.setFirstResult(pageable.getPageNumber());
    c.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());
    List<Article> result = c.list();
    Page<Article> articlePages = new PageImpl<>(result);
    return articlePages;
}
```

```
<div th:fragment='paginationbar'>
    <div>
        <ul class='pagination pagination-centered'>
            <li th:class="${page.firstPage}?'disabled':''"><span
                th:if='${page.firstPage}'>← First</span> <a
                th:if='${not page.firstPage}'
                th:href='@{${page.url}(page=0,size=${page.size})}'>← First</a></li>
            <li th:class="${page.hasPreviousPage}? '' : 'disabled'"><span
                th:if='${not page.hasPreviousPage}'>«</span> <a
                th:if='${page.hasPreviousPage}'
                th:href='@{${page.url}(page=${page.number-2},size=${page.size})}'
                title='Go to previous page'>«</a></li>
            <li th:each='item : ${page.items}'
                th:class="${item.current}? 'active' : ''"><span
                th:if='${item.current}' th:text='${item.number}'>1</span> <a
                th:if='${not item.current}'
                th:href='@{${page.url}(page=${item.number-1},size=${page.size})}'><span
                    th:text='${item.number}'>1</span></a></li>
            <li th:class="${page.hasNextPage}? '' : 'disabled'"><span
                th:if='${not page.hasNextPage}'>»</span> <a
                th:if='${page.hasNextPage}'
                th:href='@{${page.url}(page=${page.number},size=${page.size})}'
                title='Go to next page'>»</a></li>
            <li th:class="${page.lastPage}? 'disabled' : ''"><span
                th:if='${page.lastPage}'>Last →</span> <a
                th:if='${not page.lastPage}'
                th:href='@{${page.url}(page=${page.totalPages - 1},size=${page.size})}'>Last
                    →</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And why shouldn't it? You should also execute a count query the get the total count of elements. Also your `c.setFirstResult` is wrong, it should be `pageNumber * pageSize` .

Comment: i have changed the c.setFirstResult to pageNumber * pageSize , same result.

Comment: Have you READ my comment... Especially the first part of it...

Comment: where should i put the count ??

Comment: You have to execute a count query, getting the total number of records and set it on the page object. Else it will not know/calculate how many pages there are.

Comment: But the Page object has not method for set total records count.

Comment: It has a constructor for that. Instead of hacking, I suggest you do some reading of the API and what it needs/does.